# C++ What version of directx?

Tags: c++, c, directx, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DirectX 9 or DirectX 10 for starters ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571697/directx-9-or-directx-10-for-starters)

I'm started to get into a little game programming and I have some learning materials for C++/Directx 9 and 10, and im wondering which I should learn first/use.
I read somewhere windows XP doesn't have directx 10, so if i wanted to support XP, id have to use 9? Or is it backwards compatible?

Comment: That other question (this one this was marked as a duplicate of) doesn't consider runtime/OS restrictions (and most of the answers totally ignore them as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectX 10 is not supported on Windows XP so in order to run on such systems a DirectX 9 or earlier engine is required. However unless you are developing on a Windows XP system you should not worry about this and use the easier version.

IMO DirectX 10 is the better platform to work with, so you should use that to learn for now.

In either case I would recommend skipping the low level programming portion and using an environment such as [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791) or [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) if you are interested in 3D development. Another option would be [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/) to be able to host it online (Flash also but that isn't free). There are also a myriad of paid and free many game development platforms available online.

I thought I was different and could manage an engine with my first game, half a decade and well over a thousand hours later, and I never even managed to get anything that could be remotely defined as a game. (Although in my defense I spent a lot of time on random tasks such as extensible engine design (3 or 4 different ones) and procedural rendering on the GPU)

Comment: Silverlight isn't a graphics framework, it's a web browser applet framework.  WPF is the (new) high-level graphics API for .NET, replacing GDI+, and it includes a number of 3D features.  And why would you choose a DirectX machine based on the development box?  You need to design for the machines that will run the program, not just your machine.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Because worrying about your deployment platform is necessary when creating your first game. And I explicitly said Silverlight is for 2D stuff, it isn't a graphics API but it provides the tools necessary to create a game.

Comment: Silverlight is 3D if you use a 3D-enabled graphics API with it (like WPF).  And deployment platform is exactly my point, if you deploy to XP you need DirectX 9, doesn't help if your development platform has DX11 support.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: What about Linux/Mac? That means you have to use OpenGL. Oh but if you wrote it in DirectX 9 you could play it on Xbox. A dual engine rendering layer would solve that problem. Worrying about your deployment platform for your first experience programming a game or even graphics in general will lead you to waste time on things that don't matter.

Comment: That's a very valid reason to use OpenGL, but he didn't say he wanted to support Linux and Mac.  He did say he was concerned about XP.